# Requesting data from Azure Functions with Rest api from database with firewall

Tags: python, azure, ip, azure-functions, firewall

I would like to build a Azure Function with Python, that requests data every minute (json) from a database, that has firewall, and store that data to CosmosDB. If I have a virtual machine and IP-address, I could allow that IP to communicate with the database. However, Azure Functions are serverless and do not have IP, so I don't know how to make this work.

Comment: What have you done so far? what is your python code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure function has outbound IP addresses. Just add all the outbound IP addresses to the firewall.

[image]

Please note that the set of available outbound IP addresses for a function app might change if you change your App Service plan pricing tier.

Also, if your function app runs in a consumption plan, the outbound IP address might also change even if you haven't take any action.

So the perfect solution is adding both `outboundIpAddresses` and `possibleOutboundIpAddresses` to the database firewall. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#find-outbound-ip-addresses) is the detailed steps to find the outbound IP addresses.

**Note:**

> When a function app that runs on the Consumption plan is scaled, a new
>   range of outbound IP addresses may be assigned. When running on the
>   Consumption plan, you may need to whitelist the entire data center.

Reference:

[Outbound IP address changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#outbound-ip-address-changes)